# Julia DataFrames concatenate multiple columns by a space

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

In DataFrames, I have 4 columns of type String. I want to concatenate all of their values with a space.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
transform(df, All() => ((a,b,c,d) -> a .* " " .* b .* " " .* c .* " " .* d) => :combined_col)
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this without using `.*` multiple times? Maybe using the `join` function?

p.s., I'm using this inside a `@chain` so I want the same style of syntax not using indexing.

UPDATE: this works but I have no idea why can someone explain?

```
transform(df, All() => ByRow((all...) -> join(all, " ")) => :combined)
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78105483/julia-dataframes-convert-all-columns-from-int-to-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain `transform(df, All() => ByRow((all...) -> join(all, " ")) => :combined)`:

1. You need `ByRow` to apply the function row-wise to your data frame.
2. The `join` function accepts an iterator as its first argument, so `all` must be an iterator (in your example, it is a tuple).
3. The `All()` source passes the selected columns as consecutive positional arguments to the function. Therefore you need `all...` to turn consecutive positional arguments into a tuple.

Instead of `all...` you could write:

```
transform(df, AsTable(All()) => ByRow(x -> join(x, " ")) => :combined)
```

The difference is that `AsTable(All())` passes the selected columns as a single positional argument to the function (in a form of named tuple). Therefore you already have an iterable to pass to `join` (since named tuple is iterable).

Going back to your original question how to use `.*` to get the result the answer is:

```
transform(df, All() => ((x...) -> foldl((p, q) -> p .* " " .* q, x)) => :combined)
```

Note that you do not need `ByRow` in this case as `.*` already does broadcasting. You would need it if you used `*` instead of `.*`:

```
transform(df, All() => ByRow((x...) -> foldl((p, q) -> p * " " * q, x)) => :combined)
```