# Julia DataFrames convert all columns from Int to String

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

Any idea why this is not working?

```
transform(df, All() .=> string; renamecols=false)
```

Isn't it supposed to apply the `string` function to all columns and as a result convert them? When adding `ByRow` it works, but an operation like this should be on entire columns not on each row.

Comment: Adding `ByRow` solves the problem, as you want to apply `string` to each column of each row and not to the entire column all at once. So try: `transform(df, All() .=> ByRow(string); renamecols=false)`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78105483/julia-dataframes-convert-all-columns-from-int-to-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe works as expected. `string` takes a whole vector and converts it to string (the vector, not its contents). To work on elements of the vector use `ByRow`, as you have commented, or use broadcasting:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x=1:2, y=3:4, z=5:6)
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y      z
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      3      5
   2 │     2      4      6

julia> transform(df, All() .=> string; renamecols=false)
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x       y       z
     │ String  String  String
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │ [1, 2]  [3, 4]  [5, 6]
   2 │ [1, 2]  [3, 4]  [5, 6]

julia> transform(df, All() .=> ByRow(string); renamecols=false)
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x       y       z
     │ String  String  String
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │ 1       3       5
   2 │ 2       4       6

julia> string.(df) # broadcasting version
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x       y       z
     │ String  String  String
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │ 1       3       5
   2 │ 2       4       6
```

The reason why in `All() .=> string` you still get a vector is that `transform` enforces that the number of rows is not changed in the result. Therefore the resulting string is reused. Note that with `combine` you would get a single row:

```
julia> combine(df, All() .=> string; renamecols=false)
1×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x       y       z
     │ String  String  String
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │ [1, 2]  [3, 4]  [5, 6]
```

To highlight the issue see how `string` operates on a vector without DataFrames.jl:

```
julia> string([1, 2])
"[1, 2]"
```

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that sometimes the first arrow has a dot `.` and sometimes it doesn't. What is the rule of thumb for when to use this `.=>` vs `=>`?

Comment: For example, to replace missing with zero we have: `transform(All() .=> ByRow(x -> coalesce(x, 0)); renamecols=false)`, but for this one: `transform(All() => ByRow((all...) -> join(all, " ")) => :COMBO)` it doesn't work if you add a dot

Comment: if you write `cols => fun` you pass all `cols` as arguments to a single `fun` call. If you write `cols .=> fun` you pass individual columns to `fun` as many times as there are columns in `cols`.